# Adjust rules to access project from different firebase project

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I use Firebase as my database (Firestore) and authentication for two projects of mine. Project A is a Portfolio and Project B a CMS. How do I have to adjust Project A's Firestore rules, so that **a logged in user from Project B** can write data for Project A?

That's how I access Project A from Project B:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/storage';


const aurigaConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAj3hGN-....",
  authDomain: "auriga-...",
  databaseURL: "https://auriga-...",
  projectId: "auriga...",
  storageBucket: "auriga-...",
  messagingSenderId: "7263...",
  appId: "1:7263..."
};

const Auriga = firebase.initializeApp(aurigaConfig, 'auriga');

export default Auriga;
```

Comment: The best description on how to set this up is in this blog post: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/12/working-with-multiple-firebase-projects-in-an-android-app.html. You'll note that this is quite involved, so in general I'd recommend using a single project for the backend and frontend and using security rules to separate access.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thank you! My intention was to manage multiple projects with one cms project though - I guess this behavior is possible by following the blog post only?